# Python file reading not working from windows childprocess

Tags: python, c++, process, child-process

I have a simple python script, that reads the lines of a file, and it works as expected:

```
fn = "c:\\tempfile.txt"
f = open(fn, 'r')
print "f", f
lines = f.readlines()
print lines
```

However, when I call this script using a Windows CreateProcess() call from C++, it doesn't work.

The `print lines`command results in:

```
[]
```

The file seems to be "opened" in both cases, based on the first print statement. Any ideas about what is going wrong here?

Below is the code I use to start processes from C++. I took it from either Stackoverflow or MSDN

```
#ifndef WINPROC_H_
#define WINPROC_H_

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
void WinProc(std::string argv) {
    std::vector<char> str(argv.begin(), argv.end());
    str.push_back('\0');

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        &str[0],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
#endif  // WINPROC_H_
```

Comment: Hard to guess without more info ... When *it works* how is it started ? `python file.py` in a cmd.exe window or ... ? And what happens if you double click the script file in windows explorer ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta When it works, I am starting with python file.py in cmd.exe. It seems to work when I double click also.

Comment: Could you show how you start it through `CreateProcess` and did you already succeeded in reading the output from a simple `cmd.exe /c echo foo` ? And ... what do you exactly mean with *it seems to work when I double click* .

Comment: @SergeBallesta What I mean by "seems" to work, is that it closes pretty quicly so it is hard to see, but it looks like the file is being read. when I run from cmd, the command python script.py, it works too. Similarly with the command cmd.exe /c python script.py

Comment: @SergeBallesta also added the CreateProcess code I use

Comment: You could try to start it with  `cmd /k python file.py` (from a GUI app) or `cmd /c start cmd /k python file.py` (if started from a console application). That way you will explicitely ask for a new cmd windows that will stay open after end of script to see what actually happened

Comment: @SergeBallesta Ok, thanks to your help I have been able to pinpoint the issue. I will update this page soon. Thanks again